# Como posso definir uma área de "delimitadora" para o meu objeto arrastável em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ola!
Tenho um objeto com funcao drag no adobe edge animate e gostaria de saber como e possivel definir uma area onde sera possivel arrastar o objeto.
grata

Comment: Eu não conheço o Adobe Edge Animate, ele funciona como DOM? com document/body e interpreta JavaScript?

Comment: ola! nao funciona com document/body... ele e bem parecido com o action scrip utilizado no adobe flash mas e com Javascript... ja tenho o seguinte codigo que e um script jquery para arrastar o objeto: 
yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'], complete: init});

function init(){
sym.$('car').draggable();
sym.$('car2').draggable();
} como faco para limitar a area do drag? muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você modificar a função de drag: Antes de você atualizar a posição do objeto "arrastável" você só precisa checar se:

- 1. o X vai ser maior que ou igual ao X do X da área;
- 2. o X + largura vai ser menor que o X da área + a largura da área;
- 3. o Y vai ser maior que ou igual ao Y do Y da área;
- 2. o Y + altura vai ser menor que o Y da área + a altura da área;

Se não, a posição do objeto não é atualizada. Onde você atualiza a posição do objeto quando arrastado você faz algo como isso:

```
if(obj.x >= limit.x && obj.x + obj.width <= limit.x + limit.width
obj.y >= limit.y && obj.y <= limit.y + obj.height ) {
    // Deve ser provavelmente assim que você atualiza a posição?
    obj.x = e.clientX;
    obj.y = e.clientY;
}
// `limit` seria algo como {x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200}
// O limit pode ser declarado de forma que possa ser usado.
// var limit = {x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200};
```

Mas parece que você está utilizando jQuery e a função de arrastar o objeto (no seu caso) é interior. Eu não conheço muito bem o jQuery. Talvez tentar atualizar o Y do objeto toda vez que o ponteiro do mouse se move pode ser funcional, caso o Y seja atualizado depois de o objeto ser arrastado.

```
sym.$('car2').mousemove(function() {
    $(this).css({'top': y});
});
```

Comment: Ola! sou nova na linguagem js, nao consegui entender muito bem onde eu preciso por os valores... o codigo que tenho ate agora e:
yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'], complete: init});

function init(){
sym.$('car').draggable();
sym.$('car2').draggable();
} e a ideia e fazer os 2 objetos "car" se moverem no eixo x e nao no eixo y - obrigada!

Comment: @miriam Não tem como fazer isso se você não está fazendo o drag de forma interior, ou há não ser que você atualize o Y do objeto arrastável enquanto o aplicativo executa.

Comment: Klaider, esse codigo que voce me indicou me parece compativel! so que eu nao consegui enteneder onde eu preciso alterar/inserir os valores da area do meu documento e a area para limitar o objeto...

Comment: @miriam Por isso mesmo você não pode limitar ! Parece que você está usando uma library. O que você pode fazer nesse caso é atualizar o Y do objeto toda vez que é arrastado com o evento 'mousemove' (ao ponteiro do mouse se mover), por exemplo.